# script run when command run

Tags: ubuntu

how can i run a script automatically whenever a command ls is run ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bad idea, but you could use an alias.

```
alias ls='/my/script.sh'
```

Put this to your .bashrc to enable it for all new sessions. You can remove the alias with `unalias ls`.

Comment: The .bashrc should be in your home directory.